# Android library or functionality for instagram like stroies

Tags: android

I want to know what functionality or library does Instagram or other applications like snapchat uses to add text on the image and then make both of them an image to post. Could anyone help me out to know that in android

I have tried text view on the image view in frame layout but it is not worth to do that

Comment: what do you mean by 'to post' ? do you mean like a share ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use RelativeLayout

```
<RelativeLayout
      android:layout_width="200dp"
      android:layout_height="200dp">

 <ImageView

            android:src="@drawable/your_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<TextView
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:text="text in center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: but I need to write text on image and how can I post both of them as an image

Comment: dude just add my code in your layout then u understand

Comment: and its not possible write text and post that an image

Comment: could you tell me how can I change this relative layout to a bitmap image

Comment: i dont know its another question and you must ask new question

Answer (score 0):

You could create a View as you require and then convert the view to a bitmap.

```
<RelativeLayout
      android:id="@+id/myView"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent">

     <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="My text" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Send the id of the above view (**@+id/myView**) to the below function to get the Bitmap

```
public static Bitmap getBitmapFromView(View view) {
    view.measure(MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight(),
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    view.layout(0, 0, view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight());
    view.draw(canvas);
    return bitmap;
}
```